# /utils/add/message - не могу сделать RegExp

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста как составить `regexp` для такой строки `/utils/add/message`? таких `/действие` может быть сколько угодно.

Такое приходит в контроллер и мне нужно разобрать какие действия делать, куда перенаправлять.

Спасибо.

Comment: А вам точно нужен регексп? Если да, то что от него ожидается, что должно быть на выходе? Или может банального `explode()` хватит?

Comment: @PinkTux я попробовал сделать `.split("/")` но это немного не то ибо появляются пустые значения. 

удобно будет найти `matcher`-ом все совпадения (группы) и извлечь их.

Comment: А в чем проблема после `.split("/")` в массиве отбрасывать пустые значение, а с остальными работать?

Comment: @I.Perevoz после `.split()` мы получаем массив строк - `String[]`. Это не List - там нельзя удалить лишний. Только путём записывания в другой массив строк. Думал как по проще и по гибче сделать.

Comment: А `myValue.replaceFirst("^/+", "").split("/+")` не подойдёт? В любом случае не получится использовать регулярку с группами, т.к. кол-во этих групп неизвестно заранее.

Comment: Ой, конечно же я про сплит :) В любом случае так и не очень понятно чего в конечном итоге хочется. Получить все пункты между разделителями или сопоставлять путь с масками?

Comment: @PinkTux Получить пункты - первый это контроллер, ну а дальше что делать в нём. получаю первый пункт перенаправляю на нужный контроллер и делаю действия.

Comment: Если время жизни данного массива довольно небольшое, то нет ничего особо страшного в том, что в нем будут лишние объекты. Опять же, при условии, что процент пустых ячеек не будет высоким, массив будет "весить" примерно столько же, сколько и `List`. Если же необходимо его долго держать в памяти и очень хочестя оптимизировать, перегоните в лист с помощью цикла с условием.

Answer (score 0):

Если уж очень не хочется делать через `.split("/")`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String checkString = "/aaa/bbb/ccc//abc/bcd/erf/ /";

    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

    if (checkString.startsWith("/") && checkString.endsWith("/")){
        String pattern = "/[A-Za-z]+";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(checkString);
        while (m.find()){
            String cmd = m.group();
            commands.add(cmd.substring(1,cmd.length()));
        }
    }

    commands.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Однако так куда проще:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String checkString = "/aaa/bbb/ccc//abc/bcd/erf/ /";

    if (checkString.startsWith("/") && checkString.endsWith("/")) {

        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] cmds = checkString.split("/");
        for (String s : cmds)
            if (s.length() != 0)
                commands.add(s);

        commands.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```